# How to create my own visual effects for games directly via the hardware

Tags: graphics, game-engine

Regardless which programming language you use and regardless which framework you use, all tutorials point out how to use sprites and connected techniques to realize graphics. But what if I want to create my own visual effects not by an animation that I import, but create them directly via the hardware. How do I do this, where do I find tutorials and what kind of book do I have to read?

Comment: I think you might be asking about something called Shaders. A shader is a kind of code that runs on the GPU to draw pixels in the hardware. Every 2D game engine ultimately gives the sprites to the GPU then a shader draws the sprite (texture) pixels to the screen. You can make a shader do almost anything. Check out [Shadertoy.com](https://www.shadertoy.com) to see all the cool things Shaders can do.

Comment: this is kind of Too broad and or off topic ... shaders might be part of the solution here however you still need techniques for types of effects ... you know rain/snow is different to light, explotion is different to both and so on ... so needs to create sprite/texture first and use it latter some can be rendered directly using primitives  possible answer would need a comprehensive list of all techniques and effects which would not fit into 30K limit anyway you should narrow your question quite a bit ... also looking for tutorials and books is off topic here...

Comment: @ Spektre didn't know about the tutorials and books issue. Thank you for you kind hint.
@ Romen thank you for your insight, especially to the link referenced, which could be a good start for me.